# Accidentally changed ip on external NIC and can't get back into server. How can i reconnect

Tags: linux, linux-networking, ifconfig

I was SSH'd into a server today and I changed the ip of my externally facing NIC and now I can't SSH back to the server. I ran the following command:

```
ifconfig eno1 <ip> netmask 255.255.255.0
```

When I meant to run it for eno2. I'm still connected to the VPN and I assume that the server is somewhere on the network. HP ILO is running but I can't get to that either.

I am physically very far away from the server and I can't get anybody to the box for a few days because of the data center it is in.

Is there a way I can get re-connected to the server?

Answer (score 1):

If you changed interface config to an IP address that is not accessible. You can try to access the server via management interface. If it is also not accessible or not configured correctly, you are out of luck.

It is enough to reboot the server if you just typed `ifconfig` command. The changes are not permanent (assuming you have an old valid config).

Comment: I do have iLO setup but I can't find the address to connect to. I know it is configured but I'm not sure how to figure out what the iLO address/port would be so that I can connect

Answer (score 0):

Well u can physically connect to server annd change NIC adress in interfaces config file.

Comment: I should have added i'm about a thousand miles away from the physical server. Edited.

Comment: well find iLO adress and connect to it , ofc if u put iLo network cable on other NIC interface on your Proliant (i supouse) server. If u connect to iLo1 you will need Windows Xp with JAVA 1.4 bcs it runs only on that version.

Comment: I do have iLO setup but I can't find the address to connect to. I know it is configured but I'm not sure how to figure out what the iLO address/port would be

Comment: Well iLO adress is often on the back of the server. If u have someone near that server to take a picture and send you via Viber or some other app that would be nice ! Otherwise i don,t have any idea how you can obtain iLO adress, maybe if u have server documentation with you . Well if u have VPN access maybe u can use some network monitoring tool to discover all connected devices on particular network.